# Manually Moving Posts/Pages/Comments/Tags from WPMU to WP3.0

Tags: wordpress

Seems when I import the WPMU's XML file into the WP 3.0 install, I lose a ton of Pages/Posts/Categories. I am now leaning towards just manually moving over the tables from WPMU to WP3.0. Yet, when I do a dump of just wp_posts I get a sql error - making me think moving the db tables from WPMU to WP3.0 will be more complex.

Any help would be appreciated in figuring out how to correctly move over these tables so I don't have to do the XML export/import all day with no results.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do, exactly? Upgrade?

If so, that's not how. ;)

I really need to know what problem you;re trying to solve by going this route, so I can give the best answer to what you want to do.

Comment: i am trying to move all content from wpmu to wp3.0. i want to do this via merging sql databases.

Comment: my problem is i have content on a wpmu site, that i need to put on to a wp3.0 site. my transfering via xml import/export feature is not working as it is leaving pages/posts/comments out.

Comment: Are you looking to go from WPMU to multsite? If so, you just need to upgrade. no need of doing anything in the database. http://wpmututorials.com/how-to/upgrading-to-3-0/

Comment: but then i will be moving over all the other blogs which i didn't want to do.